# How to get nar classpath from Nifi custom Processor?

Tags: java, classpath, apache-nifi

I would like to get a classpath corresponding to the bundled dependencies included in my nar.

**Context :**

I've coded a Custom Processor that runs a java application as a command line, like this :

```
java -cp <classpath> com.my.package.MainClass
```

My MainClass uses classes from a dependency of my nar, i.e included in the nar.

I'm trying to get the nar classpath using the system property `java.class.path` :

```
String myclasspath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

**Problem :**

By doing so i'm not having the classpath expected. The jar included in my bundle dependencies does not appear. I get a `package com.my.dependency does not exist`

A workaround is to put the jar in the nifi "lib" folder directly, but I would like to have just one nar.

**Question :**

If "java.class.path" doesn't return the classpath included in my nar, how do I get this classpath ?

Comment: Might be good to back up and understand why you are calling a Java Main method from a NiFi processor, seems unusual

Comment: Hi Bryan. Long story short : I've got a library that compiles given string of code and execute it. It's working great, and the idea is to have a processor using that library. So the library is the one running this java main method and by default getting the "java.class.path".